# oneToMany bidirectional does not work when datasource has transactions set as serializable

Tags: hibernate, spring, glassfish, jpa-2.0

i have a app that uses Spring,Struts, Hibernate and JPA. So i have two entities, Company and Location. Company is in oneToMany relation with Location, and location in ManyToOne to Company.

**Location Entity:**

```
@Entity<br>
@Table(name = "locations")<br>
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)<br>
public class Location implements Serializable, Comparable<Location> {

    private Company company;   

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id")
    public Company getCompany(){
        return this.company;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company c){      
        this.company = c;
    }
}
```

**Company Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    private List<Location> locations;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company")
    public List<Location> getLocations(){
        return this.locations;
    }

    public void setLocations(List<Location> l){
        this.locations = l;
    }

    public void addLocation(Location l){

        if (locations == null)
            locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

        if (!locations.contains(l))
                locations.add(l);

        if (l.getCompany()!=this)
            l.setCompany(this);
    }

    public void removeLocation(Location l){

        if (locations != null){             
            if (locations.contains(l))
                locations.remove(l);  
        }
    } 
}
```

and then when i want to add a new location i have a method in locationService :

**GenericService:**

```
public abstract class GenericService {

protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED,unitName = "MyPU")
protected EntityManager em;

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}
```

}

**Location Service:**

```
@Transactional
public class LocationServiceImpl extends GenericService implements iLocationService {
    @Override
    public Boolean saveLocation(LocationForm lf) {

            Location l = new Location();
            Company c = companyService.getCompany(lf.getCompanyForm().getId());
            // set all location properties here from LocationForm Obj           

            l.setCompany(c);
            this.em.persist(l);         
                c.addLocation(l);
            return true;
    }
}
```

I have to specify that as a conection pool i use glassfish JDBC Connection Pool where i have enabled transactions with repetable read level. Everything is ok now, but if a switch from repetable read to serializable saveLocation method works no more.
This is the debug log when i run `saveLocation()` with serialize transaction level:

```
INFO: DEBUG [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] (SQLStatementLogger.java:111) - 
insert 
into
    locations
    (company_id, emailTransfer, liveTransfer, name, outbound_prefix, queue_id, smsTransfer, welcomeMessage) 
values
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
INFO: DEBUG [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] (SQLStatementLogger.java:111) - 
select
    locations0_.company_id as company9_153_1_,
    locations0_.id as id1_,
    locations0_.id as id146_0_,
    locations0_.company_id as company9_146_0_,
    locations0_.emailTransfer as emailTra2_146_0_,
    locations0_.liveTransfer as liveTran3_146_0_,
    locations0_.name as name146_0_,
    locations0_.outbound_prefix as outbound5_146_0_,
    locations0_.queue_id as queue6_146_0_,
    locations0_.smsTransfer as smsTrans7_146_0_,
    locations0_.welcomeMessage as welcomeM8_146_0_ 
from
    locations locations0_ 
where
    locations0_.company_id=?
```

So then i get :

```
INFO:  WARN [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:233) - SQL Error: 1205, SQLState: 41000

INFO: ERROR [http-thread-pool-8080(5)] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:234) - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

some parts from applicationContext.xml

```
    <bean id="txManagerVA"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory"  ref="emfVA" />        
 </bean>
    <bean id="emfVA" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="vsDS" />  
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyPU"/> 
</bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="vsDS" jndi-name="jdbc/MyJndiDS"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerVA" />
```

It seems that after that insert the table is locked and no other operation can be performed upon it. As i said before if i change the Transaction Isolation to Repetable Read everything is ok.
Can someone explain me this behavior ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the em - can you show the code for that.

Comment: i have updated my code in order to answer to your question.

Comment: That looks ok. Maybe looking at the logs to check if multiple ems or connections are getting created etc might provide some pointers. The only explanation is that for some reason multiple transactions are getting created. If both these are fired as part of same transaction - the isolation level should not matter.  What db are you using - can you try a small JDBC code to simulate the same.

Comment: yes, i had the same felling that there are 2 transactions taking place in the same time, and once i remove serializable everything works ok. I use Mysql 5.1 as database.

Comment: or maybe if i use spring transactions i have to set the datasource to Non Transactional Connections Enabled ( Returns non-transactional connections). Any idea about that ?

Comment: no, don't know about the non transactional connections. Can you check you spring transaction configuration - are you using a JPATransactionManager, is tx:annotation-driven or equivalent present. INFO log enabled for spring would also help throw more light.

Comment: i`ll update the code with spring tx manager declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Add cascade level

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Location> getLocations(){
        return this.locations;
    }
```

Then add locations to company where ever and save company not the locations.You are running into a deadlock otherwise.

Comment: ok, i understand that, but right now i`m trying to add location to a company and not the other way.

Comment: Yes I get that too , just add the location to a company and save or update the company. In the code you are saving a location to the database and then updating the company which is causing the deadlock.Just try my solution and you will see what I mean.